# WebSite search does not find any result

Tags: 2013, 2010, search, content-type, site-settings

I have a 2010 Site migrated to 2013, which contains old 2010 Lists and some new 2013. In all Lists I have enabled the `Search` (advanced list settings) and clicked `Re-index List`.
All List searches and also the global Site search does not find any result.

In the homepage.aspx I add a Search and Results WebPart and tried to filter the results (`ContentTypeId:0x0100BF8BC503E8A7C4408EC409A0208792E0 {SearchBoxQuery}`). When I use one of the current site it doesn't find anything. When I try with a ContentTypeId of another Site it works...

Is there a SiteSetting I didn't find/see?
(It already set up other searches in homepages.aspx...and they work fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unortunately I was not able to find the problem. Restarting the entire server solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The site itself might be set to be not indexable. Try checking this setting:

> 1. On the site, click **Settings** > **Site Settings**.
> 2. Under **Search**, click **Search and offline availability**.
> 3. In the **Indexing Site Content** section, under **Allow this site to appear in Search results**, select **Yes** to allow the content of the site to appear in search results.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-on-a-site-to-be-searchable-2a420d01-4706-4d23-980e-c4c877113670

Comment: The settings are already set...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the search service application and made sure your site collection is included under the web application start addresses?